# Content of email doesn't show in iOS 10

Tags: iphone, email, ios10

I have a problem with showing content in email for iPhone 6S with iOS 10. Font color default is white with background is black. All other devices are showing good.
You can see picture below:

[image: iPhone6S with iOS 10 can't see words]

Comment: You need to share your code also.

Comment: I copied in jsbin link below: 
https://jsbin.com/nepojukewu/edit?html,output

Comment: You might need to place the font colour on the `<td>` closer to the font itself.